# Chart.js: summing number of items in active/shown datasets on yAxes of pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create a pie chart with the yAxes showing the number of items in active datasets, the following configuration creates the pie chart with a yAxes showing the number of all items in all datasets but doesn't update when a dataset is deactivated/hidden.

```
options = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Stuff'
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: sumOfItems,
            },
        }]
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

i tried using the beforeUpdate handler and iterating over datasets summing them up as i go, but i have found no way to determine if a dataset is active/shown or not.

```
options = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Stuff'
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: sumOfItems,
            },
            beforeUpdate: function (scale) {
                let maxValue = 0
                if (scale.chart.config && scale.chart.config.data && scale.chart.config.data.datasets) {
                    scale.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                        if (dataset && dataset.data) {
                            dataset.data.forEach(value => {
                                maxValue = maxValue + value
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }

                scale.options.ticks.max = maxValue
            }
        }]
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

i also thought of monitoring object changes in order to find changed properties when i toggle datasets on or off but Object.observe is deprecated and i haven't found an alternative...

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

found it!

```
options = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Stuff'
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: numOfItems,
            },
            beforeUpdate: function (scale) {
                let maxValue = 0
                if (scale.chart.config && scale.chart.config.data && scale.chart.config.data.datasets) {
                    scale.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                        if (dataset && dataset.data) {
                            var visibleDataSets = new Array();

                            dataset._meta[1].data.forEach(dataset => {
                                if (dataset.hidden === false) {
                                    visibleDataSets.push(dataset._index);
                                }
                            });

                            visibleDataSets.forEach(index => {
                                maxValue = maxValue + dataset.data[index];
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }

                scale.options.ticks.max = maxValue;

                if (maxValue === 0) {
                    scale.options.ticks.display = false;
                } else {
                    scale.options.ticks.display = true;
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

TL;DR `dataset._meta[1].data[i].hidden` is the answer...